# Google android login client error message

Tags: android, google-signin

I am trying to implement the login functionality of Google for android and I get an error for the following code:

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
```

in .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* it doesn't accept the "this".

it says second argument "this" is wrong. it needs a  OnConnectionFailedListener

How do I solve this ?

thanks

Comment: implement `OnConnectionFailedListener` ?

Comment: What is `this`?? Does `this` implement that interface? Probably not seeing as you get that error